# Fedora 14 install Fedora 19 software?

Tags: fedora, software-rec, yum, upgrade

I am using Fedora 14 right now and find some software in the fc14 repository is a little old.

I need some software in my machine to be updated, say, to the Fedora 19 version.

Without upgrading the system, what is the best practice to do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to update your system, or you may run into kernel incompatibilities. Seriously consider upgrading. If Fedora updates too much for your needs, consider using CentOS or Scientific Linux. Fedora 19 is in Raw Hide status at the moment. The current stable release is Fedora 18

Comment: Just to add, Fedora 14 has been EOL for a little over a year.

Comment: It should also be noted that Fedora 14 has been end-of-life for more than a year.  Really, one should not expect to use a given Fedora version for more than a year without seriously considering the upgrade path.

Comment: Updating such an ancient Fedora is probably quite a chore. Better plan on a clean install.

Comment: It is possible to upgrade from Fedora 14 using {preupgrade} .You can use {preupgrade} all the way up to {Fedora 17}

Comment: @midnightsteel, that is 4 rounds of upgrading. The required packages aren't available anymore for 14 and 15. The step from 16 to 17 is troublesome if you have / separate from /usr. It just hurts less to stash away the configuration and package list, and install 18 to match.

Comment: @vonbrand You can use `preupgrade` to move up from Fedora 14. To be safe 1 release at a time. How do I know? I did it on one of my old server a few weeks ago. It works fine. Give it a try